# using hardie backer as a temporary floor?

Tags: flooring, temporary

We are planning on tiling our kitchen when we finish our remodel, but can't do it now.  Floor needs to be replaced due to water damage, so has anyone ever heard of using hardie backer as a temporary flooring?  Painting it perhaps?  Hubby wants to try it...

Comment: I have an issue with my kitchen floor and water damage also, had not thought about this solution. Thanks for asking about something i needed, but did not know it.

Answer (score 1):

You can walk on HB as long as you like.  If it is of the 1/2" variety I seriously doubt you could damage it.  However it does emit silica dust.  If you walked on it vigorously you could kick some up and it is really not a good thing to breathe or be near food.  You can certainly paint it.  There are waterproofing paints used for backer boards like redgard... However these will generally smell like puke for a week or two and given it's in your kitchen maybe not a good idea.  I would then go with a primer coat - which might need to be scuffed up a bit with a brush before thinset/tile.

Comment: Any answer that contains 'generally smell like puke', directly related to the answer deserves an upvote in my opinion.